# Simple PHP echo help

Tags: php

How could I add an echo in here

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["torrent"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/  (HERE)   .torrent");
```

I have tried a few things with no luck.

Comment: yes, and what do you want to print? reformulate the question, please. As it is it's not a question.

Comment: Why would you want to `echo` something here???

Comment: You should read up on string concatenation. It's necessary knowledge, imo. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a mere guess, but perhaps you want to do something like that:

```
$newFileName = 'someFielenameGeneratedByYourScript';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["torrent"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $newFileName . ".torrent");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$location = "uploads/" . $name . ".torrent";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["torrent"]["tmp_name"], $location);

echo $location;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to echo, since you are passing it to a function not trying to display it in the output.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["torrent"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/  ".$variable."   .torrent");
```